# Wordpress .mo file not always detected

Tags: wordpress, gettext, wpml

i translated a wordpress site into simplified chinese, spanish, korean and deutsch with the help of WPML and .po/.mo files on wp-content/languages

All the languages editing went well, and i'm now finalizing the site. I need to translate three last strings. All is working on all languages, except simplified chinese (zh-hans):

I add the three new entries, i generate the .mo file with poedit, and nothing changes. The already translated string stays, and the news doesn't appears.

For testing, i removed the .mo file of simplified chinese, the site remains translated without changes. I'm stuck on it, are the translated strings in the database ? Is there .mo file caching from wordpress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, WPML switched the locale from zh-hans to zh-cn without asking, regenerating .po and .mo.

Using a versioning system, i didn't saw the new files as they were generated by Wordpress.

Hope it helps